# jQuery link popup window

Tags: jquery

As you can see, I have a button and a link.

From the link when you clicked at the link the popup window will appear. How can I do that in the button using Jquery?

I want to remove the link. I want the button to act like a hyperlink

How can I replace the link with the button?

Where should I declare the link in the button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.popup').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open(
                $(this).attr("href"),
                "popupWindow", 
                "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes"
            );
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="google" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" style="width:54">
    <a href="http://google.com" class="popup">google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the link in a `data` attribute. Then the jQuery can use the `data()` method to get it

```js
$("input.popup").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).data("href");
  alert("Opening "+target);
  window.open(target, "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes"
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="popup" value="Google" data-href="http://google.com" style="width: 54;">
```

The popup doesn't work in the code snippet because SO has it sandboxed, so I added the alert.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.However..if I want to remove the hyperlink..and replace it with the button only..How can I do that?Where should I declare the link?

Comment: Anyone?please help me. I'm new in Jquery

Comment: It should work on your page. Read the last line of my answer for why it doesn't appear here. If you open the Javascript console, you'll see the detailed message.